# Перевод в восьмеричную систему счисления

Tags: python, рекурсия

```
def printOct(a):
    if a > 1:
        printOct(a // 8)
    print(a % 8, end="") 
n = int(input())
printOct(n)
```

Мне нужно выполнить перевод в восьмеричную систему счисления с помощью рекурсии. 
В принципе выводит все правильно, проблема в том что например при входе 55 выводит 067 вместо 67, как пофиксить не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if a > 0:
    print(a % 8, end="")
```

```js
function printOct(a) {
  if (a > 1)
    printOct(Math.floor(a / 8));
  if (a > 0)
    console.log(a % 8);
}

printOct(55);
console.log("");
printOct(66);
console.log("");
printOct(80);
```

Comment: Ну это не совсем то потому что это будет убирать все 0 в числе, то есть 66 теперь станет 12 а не 120

Answer (score 0):

```
def printOct(a):
    if a > 8:
        printOct(a // 8)
    elif a == 8:
        print('1', end='')
    print(a % 8, end="")


n = int(input())
printOct(n)
```

Думаю, что так должно работать. Но опять же, сей код работает только для неотрицательных целых чисел. Если нужен знак "-", то нужно добавить дополнительное условие.